# When auxiliary verb can be dropped in questions

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, auxiliary-verbs

There are two questions:

---

**When do our classes finish on Tuesday?**

**What makes him feel amazed?**

---

I can't wrap my mind around why does the first question have "do" as an auxiliary verb, but the other doesn't have any. Or is "makes" one?

Comment: Your question contains another example: it should be "... why the first question has ..."

Comment: [correction: I can't wrap my mind around why the first question **has** "do" as an auxiliary verb.] Why does x is for direct questions. Yours is not a direct question so the does/have is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the principle:

> When *what, who, which* or *whose* is the subject or part of the subject, we do not use the auxiliary. We use the word order subject + verb.

You can see this if you look at the statement versions of your questions:

Question 1: When do our classes finish on Tuesday?
Statement 1: Our classes finish at ___ o'clock on Tuesday.

Question 2: What makes him feel amazed?
Statement 2: ___ makes him feel amazed.

You can see that in question 1, we're *not* asking about the subject of the statement.  In question 2, we *are* asking about the subject of the statement.

Reference: [Questions: wh- questions - English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions)

Comment: You could rewrite the question as "Our classes on Tuesday finish when?" to eliminate the auxiliary in that case.